# how do you subset the data frame given the variable name?

Tags: r

my data frame:

```
library(usl)
dput(df)
structure(list(load = c(1L, 18L, 36L, 72L, 108L, 144L, 216L), 
    throughput = c(64.9, 995.9, 1652.4, 1853.2, 1828.9, 1775, 
    1702.2)), .Names = c("load", "throughput"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

xv=c("load")
yv=c("throughput")

capacity<-c(30)
```

I create the model using nls:

```
usl.model <- usl(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)
```

given this model, I need to do some prediction given the growth in load:

```
growth<-c(20)

pred<-predict(usl.model, data.frame(xv = tail(df[,xv],1)*(1+capacity/100)))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , object@regr, drop = TRUE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

how do I refer to xv in the predict function? Since xv is variable?

Comment: Until I find the right duplicate: `df[[yv]]`.

Comment: @joran, I don't think it is the duplicate. I'm having problem where I set the new value to the pred function data.frame(xv= how could I reference xv since it is a variable?

Comment: You could convince me of that if you finished making your example reproducible. Where can I find `usl`? What is `capacity`?

Comment: @joran, I've just updated the post. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you edited your question, it included an error for which the duplicate I suggested was the solution. You can't refer to column names in a variable using `$`.

Then you changed the question to reveal that you also had a second problem, which is that your original data frame has a variable named `load` and the new data frame has to have the column with the same name.

Just use `setNames`:

```
new_df <- setNames(data.frame(tail(df[,xv],1)*(1+growth/100)),xv)
pred<-predict(usl.model,newdata = new_df)
```